# Mechanizing Herbrand’s theorem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, automated-theorem-proving

I study automated theorem proving using [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521899575).

The author describes mechanizing Herbrand’s theorem by Gilmore procedure:
[Skolemize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form) negated FOL formula and then tests Herbrand models for satisfiability. Basically transforms FOL proving to Boolean satisfiability problem.

There is a simple example ([Drinker paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox)) that I can not understand:

1. FOL formula: $\exists x \forall y$ such that $P(x) \implies P(y)$
2. Negated and Skolemized: $\forall x$ such that $P(x) \wedge \neg P(f_y(x))$
3. The first ground instance to be generated is: $P(c) \wedge \neg P(f_y(c))$
4. Since this is still propositionally satisfiable, a second instance is generated:  $P(f_y(c)) \wedge \neg P(f_y(f_y(c)))$
5. Since the conjunction of these two instances is propositionally unsatisfiable (the conjunction includes both $P(f_y(c))$ and its negation), the procedure terminates, indicating that two ground instances were used and that the formula is valid as claimed.

Why 4. is UnSAT if 3. is SAT? 
As I understand: $c \neq f_y(c)$ then $P(c) \wedge \neg P(f_y(c))$ same as propositional formula: $a \wedge \neg b$ (satisified by a=1 and b=0). Following this logic: $f_y(c) \neq f_y(f_y(c))$ then $P(f_y(c)) \wedge \neg P(f_y(f_y(c)))$ same as $c2 \wedge \neg c3$ and should be SAT. 
Can you please explain where is mistake in my understanding?

Comment: Why in step 1  the formula has been negated?

Comment: p is a tautology if and only if ¬p is unsatisfiable

Comment: Perfect; if formula in step 2 is right, its skolemization is: $Pc \land \lnot Pc$. Unsatisfiable.

Comment: What formula are you referring to? Do you mean ground instance is: ∧¬? In my case 2 ground instances are different, they include Skolem function.

Comment: Yes, if the formula start with $∃f_y∀x$ you have no universal quantifier preceding the existential one and then the [skolem function is a constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form#Examples).

Comment: I see. My question is to understand why 3. is SAT and 4. is UnSat, can you please help with this?

Comment: I fixed a mistake after somebody edited my question. After negating ∃x∀y.p we get ∀x∃y.~p. Skolem function is not constant. Do I understand correctly? Can you please take a look at my question one more time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negation of $\exists x\, \forall y\, (P(x)\rightarrow P(y))$ is $\forall x\, \exists y\, (P(x)\land \lnot P(y))$.

Skolemizing gives $\forall x\, (P(x)\land \lnot P(f_y(x))$.

In particular, for a constant $c$, we have $P(c)\land \lnot P(f_y(c))$, and we also have $P(f_y(c))\land \lnot P(f_y(f_y(c))$. These are unsatisifable, because the first implies $\lnot P(f_y(c))$, while the second implies $P(f_y(c))$.

The conclusion is that $\forall x\, \exists y\, (P(x)\land \lnot P(y))$ is not satisfiable, so $\exists x\, \forall y\, (P(x)\rightarrow P(y))$ is valid.

Comment: So it is $P(c)\land \lnot P(f_y(c))$ AND $P(f_y(c))\land \lnot P(f_y(f_y(c))$. But not $P(c)\land \lnot P(f_y(c))$ OR $P(f_y(c))\land \lnot P(f_y(f_y(c))$ as I thought? When we search for UnSat we extend the list of clauses

Comment: @OlegDats Right, it is "and". This should be intuitive: $\forall x$ means *for all*, so the universally quantified clause is true for $c$ *and* for $f_y(c)$ *and* for every other term.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand what the author means by saying the Gilmore procedure becomes slow with each iteration. It is because the size of terms increases. Unification and smart instantiation as a solution.